# Django REST Framework: List of file paths in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer and one of the fields is a list of filepaths. This is an extra field. See below

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    temp_image_paths = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.FilePathField(
            path=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'tmp'),
        ),
        write_only=True,
        min_length=1
    )
```

The payload I'm sending to the endpoint is as follows

```
{
   ...
   "temp_image_paths": ["0ffefb78-e1e1-402a-887b-785cc55c0bf3.jpg"]
}
```

I can confirm that file exists in `path`

However, the response I'm getting from the server is

```
{
    "temp_image_paths": {
        "0": [
            "\"0ffefb78-e1e1-402a-887b-785cc55c0bf3.jpg\" is not a valid path choice."
        ]
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you show the model you are trying to serialize?

Comment: I can but the `temp_image_paths` field is not one of the model fields. It's an extra field.

Comment: Can you show then how are defining it?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The first code snippet shows how I'm defining the extra field in the serializer. Is that what you mean? Or do you still want to see the model?

Comment: Oh right, got confused a bit. It looks like the file does not exist on the given path; are you able to confirm it?

Comment: Just confirmed that it exists. I'm able to access it via browser too.

Comment: Hey. Did you manage to solve it? Am facing the exact issue and don't know how to check or solve it.